# Run chi-square test in all columns for a data_frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

There are several similar questions that grab `chi-square` results, but that solves my problem.  I'd like to calculate p.values from `chi-square` tests for all columns in a `data_frame` and store them in a column within the original `data_frame`. There will be duplicate values which I'm fine with. Ultimately, I'd like to `select` all columns in a `data_frame` that have a p.value lower than x with my variable of choice.

```
require(dplyr)

my_df <- data_frame(
  one_f = sample(LETTERS[1:5],100,T),
  two_f = sample(LETTERS[4:5],100,T),
  three_f = sample(LETTERS[5],100,T)
)
my_df %>% 
  head()

my_df %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(chisq.test(.,my_df$two_f)$p.value))
```

Gets me this error:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: 'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels.


my_df %>% 
  mutate_if(n_distinct>1,fun(chisq.test(.,my_df$two_f)$p.value))
```

Get me this error:

```
Error in n_distinct > 1 : 
  comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

I'm looking for something like this.

```
my_df %>% 
      mutate(p.value = sample(c(0.043,0.87,0.00),nrow(.),T)) %>% 
      head()
```

Then I plan to use `gather` and `filter` then `spread` to get the significantly associated variables according to my `chi-square` test.

I suppose

```
my_df %>% filter(foo,bar >= 0.05)#function that finds p.values and filters by 
# alpha level
```

would be my ultimate goal.

Comment: You mean in the title?

Comment: The process breaks because column `three_f` has only one distinct value `E`. You can have a process that removes those columns and then performs the tests to the rest of them.

Comment: Yes, my attempt at using `mutate_if(n_distinct>1, . . .)` is my attempt at overcoming that issue but it is throwing the second error message listed in the code above.

Comment: The `n_distinct` works row-wise with or without grouping to count distinct rows. It doesn't understand you want to apply it to each column. I'll post an alternative (but obviously not unique) solution.

Comment: Your example data has 100 records and three variables. You want to perform `chisq.test` on each (eligible) variable and put the (at most 3) p-values...in a variable in the same `data_frame`??? I can't think of a way that makes any sense.

Comment: I'm not sure it matters if you can't figure why I want an output the way I do. Plotting p.values over scatterplots would be one use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

my_df <- data_frame(
  one_f = sample(LETTERS[1:5],100,T),
  two_f = sample(LETTERS[4:5],100,T),
  three_f = sample(LETTERS[5],100,T)
)

# select all column names where the column has more than 1 distinct values
my_df %>% 
  summarise_all(function(x) length(unique(x))) %>%
  gather() %>%
  filter(value > 1) %>%
  pull(key) -> list_cols

# apply function only to those columns
my_df %>% 
  select(list_cols) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(chisq.test(.,my_df$two_f)$p.value))

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#     one_f                      two_f
#     <dbl>                      <dbl>
#   1 0.880 0.000000000000000000000120
```